# Minting new position vs create new pool UniswapV3?

Tags: uniswap, defi, liquidity-provider

What is the difference between minting new position and creating new pool in adding liquidity?

Answer (score 0):

The process of creating a pool happens in the factory contract meanwhile minting a new position is in nonfungiblepositionmanager one.